# can we have bash tests in maven build process for java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, maven, integration-testing

If my main logic is written using java (a small daemon server), but my test cases is a bash script. How can I include the test into my maven pom.xml? so that I can run my test using mvn command?

Comment: I have [a question about trying to do a similar thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014803/how-do-i-call-a-ruby-script-as-part-of-the-maven-build-process) using the Maven exec plugin that Alex suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to run your bash script.