# How do I call a ruby script as part of the Maven build process?

Tags: java, unit-testing, build-process, maven-3, exec-maven-plugin

**edit 2: I found the problem. The quick answer is that the lack of an `<id>` for my newly configured execution was causing the problem. I'll leave the question here in case it helps someone else.**

I have a ruby script which generates some of my jUnit source files.

I am trying to use the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to call this ruby script during the generate-sources phase of the [default lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). Here's what I've added to my POM to achieve this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <executable>ruby</executable>
            <workingDirectory>supporting_files/ruby</workingDirectory>
            <arguments>
                <argument>CreateUnitTests.rb</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This seems to be working when I'm doing a "Clean and Build Main Project" in netbeans (`clean install`), but when I run the project (`process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec` with the properties:)

```
exec.classpathScope=runtime
exec.args=-enableassertions -classpath %classpath org.example.MyProject.App
exec.executable=java
```

The run fails, <strike>because it tries to use `ruby` as the exec.executable</strike> (as I tell it to in the POM).

So, <strike>how do I use `ruby` temporarily (to run `ruby supporting_files/ruby/CreateUnitTests.rb` before running jUnit tests), but use `java` otherwise?</strike> *What's the "proper" way to call scripts during the generate-test-sources phase*?

**edit: the problem seems to be more than just changing which executable is being called...**

I wrote a quick java program which just calls the ruby interpreter, passing it (ruby filename) it received as a command line argument:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class RunRuby {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {        
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        run.exec("ruby "+args[0]);
    }
}
```

which allowed me to avoid changing the executable in my POM:

```
    <plugin>
        <!-- use ruby to generate some jUnit tests -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <executable>java</executable>
            <workingDirectory>supporting_files/ruby</workingDirectory>
            <arguments>
                <argument>RunRuby</argument>                    
                <argument>CreateUnitTests.rb</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Ugly, I know.  But anyway, a clean/build still works as expected, but the "run" is still failing! Here's the error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (default-cli) on project MyProject: Result of cmd.exe /X /C "java -enableassertions -classpath C:\Dropbox\dev\java\MyProject\target\classes;C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\LOTS\OF\JARS org.example.MyProject.App" execution is: '-1'. -> [Help 1]
```

So, it's back to running `java`, but still failing.  One odd thing I'm noticing is that it's executing the goal `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec` even though in the POM I'm telling it to use version `1.2`...

Comment: Seems like the problem isn't just the exec.executable, I'll edit my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of an `<id>` caused my customized execution to become the default.  Here's the fix:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <!-- use ruby to generate some jUnit tests during generate-test-sources -->
                <id>generate-test-sources</id>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>ruby</executable>
                    <workingDirectory>supporting_files/ruby</workingDirectory>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>CreateUnitTests.rb</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>                    
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Drews, worked well for me! I wanted something to run my rspec tests as part of a build and fail them if they don't run.